# Update request cookie for Varnish ESI-include requests from initial `beresp`

Tags: varnish, cookies

I have an application that is fronted by a Varnish server. Parts of the page is rendered using ESI includes.

My problem is that the upstream response includes an encrypted session cookie, which among other things contains a CSRF token (no server-side session storage at all).

For an initial request (no cookie in the request), the ESI requests will not include a cookie set by the first response from the upstream server.

I've tried setting `req.http.Cookie` in the `vcl_deliver` hook, as it's the only place in the request flow I've found where both `req` and `res` are R/W accessible. However, looking at the requests with varnishlog reveals the ESI requests are unaffected and don't include the cookie.

I've done my best to trawl through the documentation, but can't find anything remotely useful.

Is it possible to achieve what I want, i.e. update `req` so that the ESI requests include the cookie returned by the initial upstream response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to make a clear distinction between a request containing a `Cookie` header and a response containing a `Set-Cookie` header.

Assuming a CSRF token was set through a `Set-Cookie` header of the parent response, you probably want to access that value through a `Cookie` request header in your ESI subrequest.

### Assuming the Cookie header already contains the CSRF token

The `req_top.http.Cookie` variable has access to the cookies of the parent request, however `req_top` not accessible in `vcl_backend_response` where the ESI placeholders are parsed.

You can bypass this limitation with the following VCL snippet:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.esi_level > 0 ) {
        set req.http.X-Parent-Cookie = req_top.http.Cookie;
    }
}
```

This will enable the `X-Parent-Cookie` header which is available in `vcl_backend_response` through `bereq.http.X-Parent-Cookie`.

### Assuming the Cookie header does not yet contain the CSRF token

It is realistic to assume that `req_top.http.Cookie` doesn't yet contain the value of the CSRF token because when ESI subrequests are processed, the `Cookie` header is not yet set by the client.

The only solution I can think off is storing the parent `Set-Cookie` value in a variable. Variables aren't supported natively in Varnish and require the official https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules to be installed.

You'll have to compile this from source.

See https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules/blob/master/src/vmod_var.vcc for the `vmod_var` API and code examples.

Comment: THANK YOU! I completely forgot about `req_top`.

Comment: To elaborate a bit, I amend `req` in `vcl_deliver`, setting `req.http.X-Updated-Cookie` when `req.do_esi == true`. Then in `vcl_recv`, when `req.esi_level > 0`, if `req_top.http.X-Update-Cookie` is set I copy it into `req.http.Cookie`. Works a treat. Thankfully global vars not required.